# Using Karabiner to map one key to alternating two keys?

Tags: macos, karabiner

Is it possible to use Karabiner to map one key to alternate between two keys? For example, pressing a a a a would result in 1 2 1 2. If not Karabiner, is there some other Mac software that can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain the purpose this kind of mapping is meant to serve?  There might be a different way to achieve that than what you are asking about.

Comment: I actually managed to do what I wanted with Logitech Lua scripting.